# std::is_same result with lvalue and rvalue reference

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference, decltype

I was playing with std::is_same utility function in combination with rvalue and lvalue reference and came across a weird behavior.

Consider this function template which checks the type of variable t.

I am using VS 2013 :

```
struct Test {};

template < class T> void h(T && t)
{ 
    cout << " Is type &&: " << std::is_same<decltype(t), T &&>::value << endl;
    cout << " Is type &: " << std::is_same<decltype(t), T &>::value << endl;
}
```

I observe the following outputs :

```
h(Test()); // is type && : 1  is type & : 0
```

which is normal for now as Test() is a temporary object, and the universal reference in parameter of h resolves to a r value reference (&& && = &&)

but consider this :

```
Test myTest;
h(myTest); // is type && : 1  is type & : 1 !!!
```

same result if i write :

```
Test &myTest = Test():
h(myTest); // is type && : 1  is type & : 1 !!!
```

and same with :

```
Test &&myTest = Test():
h(myTest); // is type && : 1  is type & : 1 !!!
```

AM I missing something ? It looks like a complete mess to me :) Are the features rvalue reference / decltype not fully supported in VS 2013?

thanks for your help

Romain

Comment: Looks completely correct to me.

Comment: How can you be both an lvalue and rvalue reference?

Comment: Hint: in the latter two cases, `T` is `Test&`.

Comment: Look for reference collapsing rules.

Comment: i did, and && & is &, so it can't be &&.. (third case)

Comment: In all cases, you call `h<Test&>`, and so `T&&` is `Test&`.

Comment: In third case, use `h(std::move(myTest));`

Comment: Even it seems completely correct , instead of saying it I believe explaining why it is completely correct will be helpful for the readers like me

Comment: ok i just got it, T && is Test & and T & is Test & & = Test &.. also, thanks

Comment: @KadirErdemDemir, you can look at my answer.

Comment: let's summarize first case and the other cases can be deduced : h is instanciated with Test &&, so the parameter T&& is Test && && = Test && , and T & is Test && & = Test &. Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

Romain, it is easy enough. Let's condider following case:

```
Test myTest;
h(myTest); // is type && : 1  is type & : 1 !!!
```

Inside h, T is `Test&`, and t is of type `Test& &&`, that is, `Test&`. When you do the test, `std::is_same<decltype(t), T &&>` is true, since `Test& &&` is `Test&`, and `t` type is `Test&`.

`std::is_same<decltype(t), T &>` is also true, since `t` type is `Test&`, and `T&` is `Test&&`, which is `Test&`.

Careful application of reference collapsing rules helps here.

A bit on why inside h() T is of type `Test&`. The reason is that it is the only type of T which will match the actual argument. T can not be simply `Test`, since Test&& will not bind(match) lvalue of type `Test` (as this is the argument type). However, `Test& &&` will, because of reference collapsing rules.

Comment: I couldn't understand two things why "Inside h, T is Test&" and why "Test&&, which is Test&". It should me my lack of knowledge about r-values. Can you explain those two phrases please?

Comment: Yeah thanks, i did a short summary above, but yeah, this was essentially a reference collapsing rules story

Answer (score 3):

I will start here:

```
template < class T> void h(T && t)
{ 
  std::cout << " Is type &&: " << std::is_same<decltype(t), T &&>::value << '\n';
  std::cout << " Is type &: " << std::is_same<decltype(t), T &>::value << '\n';
}
```

In the first test, you ask if `decltype(t)` is the same a `T&&`.

For a variable, `decltype(variable)` is the declaration type of the variable.  Look at how `t` is declared -- it is `T&&`.

Not surpisingly, `decltype(t)` is the same as `T&&`, because `T&& t` is declared as a `T&&`.

This is true *regardless of what `T` is*.  So no matter what type `T` you pass, you'll get true on that line.

Grab this.  Understand this.  No type you can match for `T` could make the first line ever not print `1`.  If you get confused about the first line, come back to the fact that it is doing `std::is_same< T&&, T&& >::value`.  Whatever the rules for what `T&&` is, both sides will be the same.

But wait, you say, isn't `T&&` an rvalue reference?  Well, usually.  If type type `T` is a reference type, then reference collapsing rules apply.  `T&&` when `T=X&` becomes `X&`, not `X&&`.  lvalue reference wins out over rvalue reference.

This, with special deduction rules, is what powers forwarding references (aka universal references).

When you pass an lvalue of type `X` to `h`, it deduces `T=X&`.

When you pass an rvalue of type `X` to `h`, it deduces `T=X`.

In the first case, `T&&` becomes `X&`, and in the second it becomes `X&&`.

In your concrete case, `Test()` is an rvalue of type `Test`, which means `h(Test())` deduces `T=Test`, and we get `T&&`=`Test&&` while `T&`=`Test&`.  The code prints 1 then 0, as `T&&` (aka `decltype(t)`, aka `Test&&`) is the same as `T&&`, but not `T&`.

In the second concrete case, `h(myTest)` has `myTest` as an lvalue (even if it was declared as `Test&&`, it is an lvalue, as it has a name).  Then `T` is `Test&`, and `T&&` is `Test&` and `T&` is `Test&`.  The function prints out 1 then 1, as `T&&` (aka `decltype(t)`, aka `Test&`) is the same as `T&&` and `T&`.

To fix your problem, do this:

```
template < class T> void h(T && t)
{ 
  using rawT = std::remove_reference_t<T>;
  std::cout << " Is type &&: " << std::is_same<decltype(t), rawT &&>::value << '\n';
  std::cout << " Is type &: " << std::is_same<decltype(t), rawT &>::value << '\n';
}
```

and you get the output you expect.